# how to make it that it does not repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that a "not repeat with random from a list" is probably seen as a info you can find, but as someone who does not have a lot of knowledge of python yet, i cannot seem to understand those answers or they do not work for my problem. So I hope any of you are able to help.

as my first small project I am building a truth or dare program, and now I am at the point that I  want to make it that the questions cannot be asked twice, and that if the truth questions are all done it prints that announcement, and I want the same for my dare questions.
here is my program so far, sorry if it is messy:

```
import random
import time

truth = ["If you could be invisible, what is the first thing you would do?",
"What is a secret you kept from your parents?",
"What is the most embarrassing music you listen to?",
"What is one thing you wish you could change about yourself?",
"Who is your secret crush?"]


dare = ["Do a free-style rap for the next minute",
"Let another person post a status on your behalf.",
"Hand over your phone to another player who can send a single text saying anything they want to anyone they want.",
"Let the other players go through your phone for one minute.",
"Smell another player's armpit."]



print("Hello, and welcome to my truth or dare show, just type truth or type dare to get a question!")
lives = 3
while lives > 0:
    choice = input("truth or dare?: ").lower()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    if choice == "truth":
        print(random.choice(truth))
        time.sleep(0.5)

        while True:
            answer_truth = input("want to answer? type yes or no: ").lower()

            if answer_truth == "yes":
                input("> ").lower()
                print("good answer")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"you have {lives} lives left")
                break

            elif answer_truth == "no":
                print("you lost a life!")
                time.sleep(1)
                lives -= 1
                print(f"you have {lives} lives left")
                break

            else:
                print("that is not an option")

    elif choice == "dare":
        print(random.choice(dare))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        while True:
            do_dare = input(f"did you do the dare? type yes or no: ").lower()

            if do_dare == "yes":
                print("well done!")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"you have {lives} lives left")
                break

            elif do_dare == "no":
                print("you lost a life!")
                lives -= 1
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"you have {lives} lives left")
                break

            else:
                print("that is not an option")

    else:
        print("that is not an option")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("GAME OVER!")
```

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking about or what "it" is

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
choice = random.choice(truth)
time.sleep(0.5)
# inside the loop
truth.remove(choice)

if len(truth) == 0:
    print("all questions are done")
```

do the same for dare

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a construct like this:

```
from random import shuffle
ls = ["a", "b", "c"]
shuffle(ls)
lives = 3

while lives > 0 and ls:
    current_question = ls.pop()
    ...  # Rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to select a random option, but then no longer have it in the set that you select random things from in the future.

If you imagine it physically, you have a jar `list` that has papers `item`'s in it and you want to take them out at random. Obviously, any that you take out can not be taken out again.

We can accomplish this by removing the item from the list after it's 'picked'

To answer your question about having it let them know there are no more truths or no more dares, we can simply add a conditional to the whole `truth` segment and one to the whole `dare` segment as well, then further, if both run out, end the game.

```
while lives > 0 and (len(truth)>0 or len(dare>0)):
# Rest of the program
```

```
if choice == "truth":
    if len(truth) > 0:
        # Code
    else:
        print("there are no more truths (existential crisis), maybe try a dare instead")
```

```
elif choice == "dare":
    if len(dare)>0:
        # Code
    else:
        print("there are no more dares *sigh of releif*, maybe try a truth instead")
```